# Are there issues when I create duplicate objects in controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While creating some apps I noticed I create multiple instances of the same objects within my controller in order to have access to them from different pages. For example:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all 
  @category = Category.new 
end

def new
  @category = Category.new 
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Does such repetition influence the loading speed of my application, and if there are ways to optimize it? Or should I just relax and keep creating new objects inside my methods?

Comment: It doesn't affect the loading speed, except in a minuscule amount because the parser has to read four more lines. It *might* affect run-time speed, but that's a different question and we'd have to know a whole lot more about your application to answer it.

Comment: Do you really need `@category` in `index` and `@categories` in `show`?

Comment: I was just making a point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reduce some time using || operator, to store end result of an expensive command in an instance variable!

```
def index
  @categories ||= Category.all 
  @category = Category.new 
end

def new
  @category = Category.new 
  @categories ||= Category.all
end
```

watch this railscasts video

http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables